# Including all post id's of a custom post type into an array

Tags: custom-post-types, php, loop, single

For my single.php (products.php), I try to build a navigation via which the user can switch between products based on the meta key "price". I want to put all id's of the products post type into an array and then identify the previous and next product for the navigation, based on the price meta key.

Somehow I don't manage to get the code work:

**SINGLE.PHP**

```
<?php
// Setting up the loop
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'products', 
'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_key' => 'price',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts_query = new WP_Query($args);

// Setting up the array in which ALL IDs of all product posts will be stored
$posts = array();

// Starting the loop
while ($posts_query->have_posts()) {
    // Including the post IDs one by one    
    $posts[] += $post->ID;
}

$current = array_search(get_the_ID(), $posts);
$prevID = $posts[$current-1];
$nextID = $posts[$current+1];

if (!empty($prevID)) { ?>
<a href="www.example.com/post_type=products&post_id=<?php 
echo $prevID; ?>">previous product</a>
<?php }
if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>
<a href="www.example.com/post_type=products&post_id=<?php 
echo $nextID; ?>">next product</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Does anyone see the error(s)?

Comment: i think, you need to call  wp_reset_postdata(); after the while loop

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but the code doesn't work. I managed to find a solution which I posted as an answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73190/can-the-next-prev-post-links-be-ordered-by-menu-order-or-by-a-meta-key/145067#145067

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself a loop with `get_posts` and `'fields' => 'ids'`.

```
// Default Query

function do_query($args = null) {
    $default_args = array( 
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids',
    );

    if (null !== $args && !empty($args))
        $args = array_merge($default_args, $args);
    else 
        $args = $default_args;

    return get_posts($args);
}

// Customize Query

$post_ids = do_query ( 
    array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'meta_key' => 'price',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
));

// Search for the index of the ID / prev / next

$currentID = get_the_ID(); 
$currentINX = array_search( $currentID, $post_ids);

$count = count($post_ids);

$prevINX = $currentINX - 1;
if ( $prevINX < 0 ) $prevID = FALSE;
else $prevID = $post_ids [ $prevINX ];

$nextINX = $currentINX + 1;
if ( $nextINX >= $count ) $nextINX = FALSE;
else $nextID = $post_ids [ $nextINX ];

// Output links

if ( $prevID ) {
    $link = get_permalink ( $prevID );
    echo "<a href=\"${link}\">previous product</a>";
}

if ( $nextID ) {
    $link = get_permalink ( $nextID );
    echo "<a href=\"${link}\">next product</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you use the custom query, you need to call the `wp_reset_postdata()` function, to reset the global post data, before using functions like `get_the_ID()`

```
<?php
// Setting up the loop
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'products', 
'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_key' => 'price',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts_query = new WP_Query($args);

// Setting up the array in which ALL IDs of all product posts will be stored
$posts = array();

// Starting the loop
while ($posts_query->have_posts()) {
    // Including the post IDs one by one    
    $posts[] += $post->ID;
}

wp_reset_postdata(); //reset the global post data



$current = array_search(get_the_ID(), $posts);
$prevID = $posts[$current-1];
$nextID = $posts[$current+1];

if (!empty($prevID)) { ?>
<a href="www.example.com/post_type=products&post_id=<?php 
echo $prevID; ?>">previous product</a>
<?php }
if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>
<a href="www.example.com/post_type=products&post_id=<?php 
echo $nextID; ?>">next product</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but the code doesn't work. I managed to find a solution which I posted as an answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73190/can-the-next-prev-post-links-be-ordered-by-menu-order-or-by-a-meta-key/145067#145067