# Why the pagination for a query modified by pre_get_posts doesn't mind the number & order of posts sorted & selected based on a custom date time field

Tags: custom-field, pagination, pre-get-posts

I have the following task I'm trying to accomplish. I want to display events in the `post` post type. I want to sort them by date and time and there should be events only displayed happening right now or in the future. Old posts shouldn't be displayed in the front-end at all. Therefore I have attached a custom date time field `event_start` with `Advanced Custom Fields 5.6.10` to the post type `post`. For test purposes I have only seven posts, six upcoming and one passed with the following dates.

**Post 0**

*Publish date:* 28.06.2018

*Event date:*   05.07.2018 18:00

**Post 1**

*Publish date:* 30.05.2018

*Event date:*   06.08.2018 21:08

**Post 2**

*Publish date:* 29.05.2018

*Event date:*   06.08.2018 21:20

**Post 3**

*Publish date:* 14.07.2018

*Event date:*   10.08.2018 08:00

**Post 4**

*Publish date:* 23.07.2018

*Event date:*   12.08.2018 08:00

**Post 5**

*Publish date:* 24.07.2018

*Event date:*   23.08.2018 08:00

In the WordPress backend I've set the number of shown posts to 4. The website is using the Phlox theme which is based on Elementor. For narrowing down the posts and satisfying the described constraints I've created a small plugin utilising `pre_get_posts`. The particular function created looks like this:

```
function mv_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( class_exists( 'ACF' ) ) {
        // Queries aren't modified for the admin menu.
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            return $query;
        }
        // Queries are modified for the post type 'post' only.
        if ( isset( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && ( 'post' === $query->query_vars['post_type'] || is_single() ) ) {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_start' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', get_option( 'posts_per_page' ) );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'event_start',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value'   => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-8 hours' ) ),
                    'type'    => 'DATETIME',
                ),
            ) );
        }
        return $query;
    } else {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'mv_mvquery_notice' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mv_pre_get_posts' );
```

I've also set the `posts_per_page` as recommended here [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops) and used the `get_option` function to pull the set number automatically. If I take a look at the front-page now, `Post 1` to `Post 4` are displayed correctly on the first page. But now the issues with  pagination are about to start. If I go to the second page again `Post 1`  to `Post 4` are shown, instead of `Page 5` only, which I would have expected.

If I click onto `Page 4` to get into the single view `Post 5` is correctly shown as next as well as `Post 3` for previous. If I go on clicking the previous links further I get to `Post 0`, which shouldn't show up at all, then `Post 1` then `Post 2`.

If I start from `Post 1` in single view, instead of only seeing the next `Post 2` link I get `Post 2` for previous and `Post 0` for next. After clicking `Post 0` next, `Post 3`, `Post 4` and `Post 5` follow up.

Is there a way to make the pagination adhere to the settings for `pre_get_post` and minding the given query results for the front-page as well as for each single view with the correct sorting order and number of displayed posts?

**Update**
I've fixed the issue with the front-page pagination by setting the paged attribute. The function looks the following way now, but the issue that `Post 0` shows up when displaying single posts, and also mixing up the sort order still persists. :/

```
function mv_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( class_exists( 'ACF' ) ) {
        // Queries aren't modified for the admin menu.
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            return $query;
        }

        // Queries are modified for the post type 'post' only.
        if ( isset( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && ( 'post' === $query->query_vars['post_type'] || is_single() ) ) {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_start' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
            $query->set( 'paged', get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', get_option( 'posts_per_page' ) );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'event_start',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value'   => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-8 hours' ) ),
                    'type'    => 'DATETIME',
                ),
            ) );
        }
        return $query;

    } else {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'mv_mvquery_notice' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mv_pre_get_posts' );
```

**Update 2**
After a lot of fiddling I managed to create custom queries with the `get_adjacent_post` filters. Basically the posts get properly sorted now and `Post 0` isn't shown anymore:

```
function mv_adjacent_post_join() {
    global $wpdb;
    return "INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS mvpm ON mvpm.post_id = p.ID";
}
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_join', 'mv_adjacent_post_join' );
add_filter( 'get_next_post_join', 'mv_adjacent_post_join' );

function mv_previous_post_where() {
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $mv_event_start = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-8 hours' ) );
    return $wpdb->prepare( " WHERE mvpm.meta_key = 'event_start' AND CAST(mvpm.meta_value AS DATETIME) >= %s AND p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish'", $mv_event_start );
}
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_where', 'mv_previous_post_where' );

function mv_next_post_where() {
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $mv_event_start = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-8 hours' ) );
    return $wpdb->prepare(" WHERE mvpm.meta_key = 'event_start' AND CAST(mvpm.meta_value AS DATETIME) >= %s AND p.post_type = 'post' AND p.post_status = 'publish'", $mv_event_start );
}
add_filter( 'get_next_post_where', 'mv_next_post_where' );

function mv_previous_post_sort() {
    return "ORDER BY mvpm.meta_value DESC LIMIT 1";
}
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_sort', 'mv_previous_post_sort' );

function mv_next_post_sort() {
    return "ORDER BY mvpm.meta_value ASC LIMIT 1";
}
add_filter( 'get_next_post_sort', 'mv_next_post_sort' );
```

The only thing I was unable to accomplish and figure out is how to compare the current post to the next and previous. In the `link-template.php` it is accomplished by comparing `p.post_date` with `$post->post_date`. But aren't those basically the same? But in my case I would have to compare the `event_start` field of the current post to the previous and next. `mvpm.meta_value > mvpm.meta_value` and `mvpm.meta_value < mvpm.meta_value` doesn't make much sense inside the SQL of the WHERE filters? :/

Comment: What is the meta `dattime`? Your question indicates that the data is stored in a field named `event_start`. Have you confirmed that your `pre_get_posts` code runs and that your conditional checks are correct? I would also note that your fix for custom loops is unnecessary because you are not using custom loops. You're instead modifying the main query, and so the fix is not necessary and may actually cause unrelated issues in some circumstances

Comment: ups sorry about the dattime. Slipped in by accident. dattime I used in my sandbox installation and event_start I chose for demonstration purposes here on the site instead. But just forgot to update the code in that direction. Sorry! Did now.

Comment: The `pre_get_post`code runs and the conditional checks are correct imho. Without the `is_single()` conditional there is `DESC` instead of `ASC` sort order for single views. So I would say the `pre_get_post` code is correct. The pagination is the issue. And i suppose I don't use the main query. If i check Query Monitor I notice there is the main query and afterwards the query containing the `event_start` custom field. And based on the fact that I am using `pre_get_post`I suppose the Phlox theme isn't utilizing the main query for the display of posts on the front page :(

Comment: hmm keep in mind that if you have pagination, you're in an archive, not a singular page, so `is_single` doesn't make sense. And yes if your theme is replacing the main query with its own then that complicate things immensely, however, I'm not so sure that what you're trying to do and what you want are quite the same, you talk about this as if it's pagination in an archive, but it is not. It's the next and previous post functionality, which is very different

Comment: I've added the is_single conditional to apply those query settings also to the query building the display of single posts. Otherwise it would rely onto the main query with differing setting (e.g. include `Post 0`). And I don't consider it an archive but the display of a single post (with `single.php`). My remaining problem is just that `Post 0`is included even though excluded by my query settings and mixing also the order clicking through with previous and next as already described in my initial post. :/  Guess the previous and next links are based on a different query not `$query`?

Comment: See [Can the Next/Prev Post links be ordered by menu order or by a meta key?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73190/can-the-next-prev-post-links-be-ordered-by-menu-order-or-by-a-meta-key)

Comment: @rpk that's correct, next and previous posts are not based on the main query, they are their own thing