# Next/Previous Product with custom order by price & products inside the product category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta, sort, next-post-link, previous-post-link

How to create next/prev buttons that are price sorted and give results inside the product category you are in?
**This question has been asked multiple times and despite the multiple threads there wasn't an exact answer. Only relatively close ones that didn't do all of the above.**

Below you will find my answer which works in my tests so far.

Comment: The first question provides no context - we can't address if your placement is correct without seeing your placement. The second question does not wholly make sense; `global $post` is just a reference to the current post object within The Loop - it is not used when constructing a new `WP_Query`. Instantiating a new `WP_Query` object also has no effect on any other query - there's no implicit reason to reset post-data.

Comment: So your answer's to my sidequestions is that wp_reset_postdata(); isn't needed when constructing a new Wp_Query and that wp_reset_postdata(); has nothing to do with the general use of global $post variable, is that correct? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error i managed to refine the code above to clear all php notices that were created by the original code and make it work properly cause there were some mistakes in the previous code.
I am happy to share the solution to next/prev products in your product pages that wont show outofstock products and will be sorted by ASC price while showing results only from inside the product category you are in!
Give a thumbs up if you found it useful! :)

```
//generate_inside_site_container is a theme specific hook, you can use a woocommerce product hook instead and remove if ( is_product() ) {, in the next line

add_action('generate_inside_site_container', 'japs_prev_next_product', 1000);
function japs_prev_next_product() {
   if ( is_product() ) {
   global $post;
   $terms = get_the_terms( !empty($product->id), 'product_cat' );  
   foreach ($terms as $term) {
   if ($term->ID == !empty($category->cat_ID)) {
   $all_posts = new WP_Query(
      array(
         'post_type' => 'product',
         'meta_key' => '_price', // <-- CHANGE THIS
         'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_stock_status',
                'value' => 'outofstock',
                'compare' => '!=',
            )
         ),      
         'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field'      => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => $terms[0]->term_id
                     )
         )
      )
   );
       if ( $all_posts->post_count <= 1) {
           return;
       }
       break;
   }
   }
   foreach ($all_posts->posts as $key => $value) {
      if ($value->ID == $post->ID) {
         $nextID = $all_posts->posts[$key + 1]->ID;
         $prevID = $all_posts->posts[$key - 1]->ID;
         break;
      }
   }
   echo '<div>';
         if ($prevID) : ?>
            
            <a href="<?= get_the_permalink($prevID) ?>" rel="prev" class="prev" title="<?= get_the_title($prevID) ?>"><?= esc_attr__('Previous product') ?>
            </a>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if ($nextID) : ?>
            <a href="<?= get_the_permalink($nextID) ?>" rel="next" class="next" title="<?= get_the_title($nextID) ?>"><?= esc_attr__('Next product') ?>
            </a>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php

   echo '</div>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to modify an existing answer from a closely related thread to achieve this.
You can find the answer from the related thread here.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/365334/185141

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'elron_prev_next_product');

// and if you also want them at the bottom...
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product', 'elron_prev_next_product');

function elron_prev_next_product() {
    
   global $post;
    
   echo '<div class="prev-next-buttons">';
   $terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );  
   foreach ($terms as $term) {
   if ($term->ID == $category->cat_ID) {
   $all_posts = new WP_Query(
      array(
         'post_type' => 'product',
         'meta_key' => '_price', // <-- CHANGE THIS
         'orderby' => 'meta_value',
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field'      => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => $terms[0]->term_id
                     )
         )
      )
   );
       break;
   }
   }
   foreach ($all_posts->posts as $key => $value) {
      if ($value->ID == $post->ID) {
         $nextID = $all_posts->posts[$key + 1]->ID;
         $prevID = $all_posts->posts[$key - 1]->ID;
         break;
         wp_reset_postdata();
      }
   }

   if ($prevID) : ?>
      <a href="<?= get_the_permalink($prevID) ?>" rel="prev" class="prev" title="<?= get_the_title($prevID) ?>"><?= esc_attr__('Previous product') ?></a>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if ($nextID) : ?>
      <a href="<?= get_the_permalink($nextID) ?>" rel="next" class="next" title="<?= get_the_title($nextID) ?>"><?= esc_attr__('Next product') ?></a>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php

   echo '</div>';
}
```

I know i was searching for a way to make next/prev button on my product pages that were sorted by price and gave products only inside the product category i was on, for a long time, if you did as well give an upvote! :)

EDIT: You can also limit the query created to output products that aren't outofstock

```
$all_posts = new WP_Query(
      array(
         'post_type' => 'product',
         'meta_key' => '_price', // <-- CHANGE THIS
         'orderby' => 'meta_value',
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_stock_status',
                'value' => 'outofstock',
                'compare' => '!=',
            )
         ),      
         'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field'      => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => $terms[0]->term_id
                     )
         )
      )
   );
```

EDIT 2: Although the above code works just fine in all my tests, there are 2 notices generated from wp_debug

```
Notice: Undefined variable: product in /public/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php on line 2098

Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in /public/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php on line 2098

Notice: Undefined variable: category in /public/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php on line 2100

Notice: Trying to get property 'cat_ID' of non-object in /public/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php on line 2100
```

2098 line:    `$terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );` 
2100 line:    `if ($term->ID == $category->cat_ID) {`

Comment: This answer does not appear to address either of the posed questions

Comment: You basically answered both of my sidequestions. And thank you, i edited the original question section a bit to reflect it! The primary thread is about constructing next/prev buttons with a loop inside the product category while price sorted... And that was tried to be answered by me!